# MPmovieplayer and streaming m3u8 file?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller, http-live-streaming, mpmovieplayer, m3u8

Am using MPMoviePlayerController to stream n play a video. Its, in `m3u8` format and plays with no problems. However, lets say it has buffered n played 50% of the total video, now if i seek backward, it starts buffering from that point. shouldn't it just play the video and not buffer from the seeked point as it has already buffered that part..??

This behaviour is observed only in case of  `m3u8` file, if I play a `mp`4 file, it doesn't do that. I mean, it won't buffer again.

So, is this an expected behaviour or am I just missing something..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`m3u8` is a playlist file. It has links to either other playlist files or video files in `TS`(transport stream) format. The `ts` files are most commonly 10 seconds chunks of video. So, every N(10) seconds it fetches a new stream.So, when you seek, it will go and fetch the stream that had that chunk of the video. So, you will see buffering again.

Comment: That indeed was a silly question to ask... later I found out that mp4 is NOT streaming, its downloading.. where in case of m3u8 it is is streaming as u explained. Thanks for the answer though..:)